# Code igniter how to define site title from user input value?

Tags: codeigniter, input, title

I'm beginner with code igniter

I want to define site title from user input value
I need create a specific Controller for it ?
  I think using this code:

view (for build a new page)

```
Site Title:<input type="text" size="40" name="title" />
```

view (generated page )

```
<title><?php echo $title ?> </title>
```

controller

```
$title   = $_POST['title'];
```

Comment: Are you wanting to change the title (I'm assuming you mean the head <title>) for a single page or for the whole site for that user?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, you may try something like below: But you should read up more on the codeigniter doc.

View File:

```
<input type="text" name="title">
```

Controller:

```
$data['title'] = $this->input->post('title');
$this->load->view('view-file-name', $data);
```

View File (view-file-name.php)

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```